# Python: NameError from calling a file from the commandline arguments

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, nameerror

For an assignment I'm supposed to have to have a line to open a file that is passed as an argument in the commandline, I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execute.py", line 1, in <module>
    program=open(programfilename, "r")
NameError: name 'programfilename' is not defined
```

My code to this point is `program=open(programfilename, "r")`. I'm not quiet sure what is wrong. It is the first line in my program. Execute.py is the name of my code.

Comment: Where exactly is it supposed to be getting `programfilename` from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the programfilename variable to the name/path of the file on a previous line. Alternatively, you could put the filename in quotes instead.

Answer (score 0):

> It is the first line in my program

Well there's your problem. You are using `programfilename` without having defined it first.

Try something like

```
import sys   
programfilename = sys.argv[0]  # argument you passed into your program. 
program=open(programfilename, "r")
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to.
If you want to call a file using command line, the code can be like this

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Run like this

```
python3 execute.py programfilename
```

If you want your program to get printed on the console, the code can be like this

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[0], 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

This will print the code on the console.

Run like this

```
python3 execute.py
```